# Use different aplication cookie or cookie options edit when login through api

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, authentication, cookies

I have a problem about api login with cookies, the goal is that before the user can call any api, the user must first call /api/Authentication/Login and then he can use the rest of the operations. However, when I call for example /api/Batch, instead of returning AccessDenied, I get the full html of the login page in the body of the response which is wrong in this case.

```
services.AddScoped<IAuthenticationService, LdapAuthenticationService>();
      services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
      services.AddIdentity<User, Role>(o => {
        o.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
        o.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
        o.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
        o.Password.RequireDigit = true;
        o.Password.RequireUppercase = true;

      }).AddEntityFrameworkStores<ScanLinkContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders().AddRoles<Role>();

      services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
      .AddCookie(options =>
      {
        options.LoginPath = "/Account/SignIn";

      });
      
      services
         .ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
         {
           options.Cookie.Name = ".AspNetCore.Cookies";
           options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
           options.LoginPath = "/Account/SignIn"; // If the LoginPath is not set here, ASP.NET Core will default to /Account/Login
                 options.LogoutPath = "/Account/SignOut"; // If the LogoutPath is not set here, ASP.NET Core will default to /Account/Logout
                 options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/SignIn"; // If the AccessDeniedPath is not set here, ASP.NET Core will default to /Account/AccessDenied
                 options.SlidingExpiration = true;
           options.ReturnUrlParameter = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.ReturnUrlParameter;
         });
```

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {


      if (env.IsDevelopment())
      {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "WEBAPI v1"));
      }
      else
      {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
        app.UseHsts();       
      }

      app.UseSession();
      app.UseHttpsRedirection();
      app.UseStaticFiles();
      app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("/Errors/{0}");
      app.UseRouting();
      // Add authentication to request pipeline
      app.UseAuthentication();
      app.UseAuthorization();

      app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
      {
        endpoints.MapRazorPages();
               
        endpoints.MapControllers();
        
      });
    }
```

I need to leave the original configuration, so that it is functional for the web and in the case of visiting a page to which the user has the right, it redirects him to the login page, but for the cookie I would need a different behavior as described above

```
    [Authorize]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class BatchController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ScanLinkContext _scanlinkContext;
        public BatchController( ScanLinkContext scanLinkContext)
        {
                _scanlinkContext = scanLinkContext;
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }
        [Route("Import")]       
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<StatusCodeResult> PostImport([FromBody] string xml)
        {
            return Ok();
        }
        [HttpPut("[action]/{batchName}")]
        public async Task<StatusCodeResult> Tranform(string batchName, [FromBody] string json)
        {
            return Ok();
        }
        [HttpPut("[action]/{batchName}")]
        public async Task<StatusCodeResult> Validate(string batchName, [FromBody] string json)
        {
            return Ok();
        }
        [HttpPut("[action]/{batchName}")]
        public async Task<StatusCodeResult> Unlock(string batchName)
        {
            return Ok();
        }
        [HttpDelete("{batchName}")]
        public async Task<StatusCodeResult> Delete(string batchName)
        {
            return Ok();
        }
    }
```

How should I adjust the configuration to achieve the goal?

Comment: Your AccessDenied path redirects you to your login page.

Comment: @GHDevOps Yes, that's corect in case i want to login through login page, but I don't want that when I login through API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to override the Events.OnRedriectLogin like this.

```
 .ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
         {
//other options...
      options.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = context =>
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        };

}
```

Comment: I tried, but no change, still in Swagger UI it returns whole html page in response body with code 200

Comment: What if you put it under .AddCookie instead of ConfigureApplicationCookie? And maybe remove that loginpath under .AddCookie.

Comment: If I put it under the AddCookie, then breakpoint will not even hit. If I remove LoginPath, then it's not redirecting to login page and it's still reponse with while html. When it's like in your answer, breakpoint will hit then set se statusCode properly a then still whole html is coming back...

Comment: It is a known issue, see here. https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/9039

Comment: EDIT if I add the OnRedirectToLogin it'not returning the login page now, but the whole page 401.cshtml

Comment: If I remove app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("/Errors/{0}"); then it's working, but when I go to page which i don't havev rights in application then it shows the page not working stuff. I would be nice if I can use some ifs for this